# Spring JMS transport the onSendAfterWrite in JMSReceiverConnection sends TextMessage[ID:<507866.1373381341790.0>, null] in response

Tags: spring, queue, jms, reply, transport

The JMSRecieverConnection.send() flushes the response to transport output stream and returns the responseMessage to replyQueue. But the responseMessage is TextMessage[null, null]. Here is the code I am using, can anybody help in finding what is going wrong?

- Consumer Configuration

JMS transport configuration,

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName"
            value="temp.connection" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Bean definition for jndi template -->
    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="testQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName"
            value="temp.test.request" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <bean id="defaultMessageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="testQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.WebServiceMessageListener">
                <property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory"/>
                <property name="messageReceiver" ref="messageDispatcher"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">
        <property name="endpointMappings">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
                <property name="mappings">
                    <props>
                        <prop
                            key="{http://www.test.com/schema/mms/MSGM}ExampleRequest">exampleRequestEndpoint</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
                <property name="interceptors">
                    <list>
                        <!-- ref bean="validatingInterceptor" /> -->
                        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

- Client code,

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, Exception

            {
              String  messageID                 = null;
              String  outString                 = null;
              String  qcfName                   = "temp.connection";
              String  qnameIn                   = "temp.test.request";
              String  qnameOut                  = "";
              boolean verbose                   = false;

              QueueSession           session    = null;
              QueueConnection        connection = null;
              Context                ctx        = null;

              QueueConnectionFactory qcf        = null;
              Queue                  inQueue    = null;
              Queue                  outQueue   = null;

              FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("c:/myMsgm.xml"));
              StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
              IOUtil.copyCompletely(fr, sw);
              outString = sw.toString();
              System.out.println("input : "+sw.toString());
              Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
              ht.put("weblogic.jndi.replicateBindings", "false");
              ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
              ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
              ctx = new InitialContext(ht);

              qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup( qcfName );
              inQueue = (Queue)ctx.lookup( qnameIn );
              outQueue = (Queue)ctx.lookup( qnameOut );

              connection = qcf.createQueueConnection();
              connection.start();
              boolean transacted = false;
              session = connection.createQueueSession( transacted, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
              QueueReceiver queueReceiver =null;
              QueueSender queueSender = null;

              time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();
              for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                      queueSender = session.createSender(inQueue);
                      TextMessage outMessage = session.createTextMessage(outString);
                      Queue tempQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
                      outMessage.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
                      queueSender.send(outMessage);
                      messageID = outMessage.getJMSMessageID();

                      System.out.println("Message ID : "+messageID);
                     // String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '"+messageID+"'";

                      queueReceiver = session. createReceiver(tempQueue);
                      Message inMessage = queueReceiver.receive();
                     System.out.println("inMessage type : "+inMessage.getJMSType());
                     System.out.println("inMessage : "+inMessage);


                      if ( inMessage instanceof TextMessage ){
                          String replyString = ((TextMessage) inMessage).getText();
                          System.out.println("response message : "+ replyString);
                      }

              }
              System.out.println("start time : "+ time);
              System.out.println("end time : "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

              sw.close();
              queueReceiver.close();
              queueSender.close();
              session.close();
              session = null;
              connection.close();
              connection = null;

  }
  ```
- Output

> Message ID : ID:<507866.1373381334004.0> inMessage type : null 
>   inMessage : TextMessage[ID:<507866.1373381341790.0>, null] response 
>   message : null start time : Tue Jul 09 15:48:53 BST 2013 end time : 
>   Tue Jul 09 15:49:01 BST 2013

- Debugging result

The responseMessage is TextMessage[ID:<507866.1373381341790.0>, null] while sending reply to replyQueue in onSendAfterWrite of JMSReceiverConnection.

Comment: This problem is fixed using Spring-ws-core 1.5.4. This was a bug in spring-ws-core 1.5.1 and fixed from 1.5.3. Thanks to the people who have taken a look to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed using Spring-ws-core 1.5.4. This was a bug in spring-ws-core 1.5.1 and fixed from 1.5.3. Thanks to the people who have taken a look to resolve it.

reference: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-367

Prabhu